# Pytorch CUDA not available with correct versions

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I really need help setting up CUDA for development with Pytorch. I have a Nvidia graphics card and am using Python 3.8. To install pytorch with the correct CUDA integration I ran `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c python`. The problem is that `torch.cuda.is_available()` always returns `False`.

Can anyone help me here?
I the following are my versionings:

`nvcc --version`

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

`nvidia-smi`

NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6

Answer (score 0):

As in the [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) website, install with `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch` or `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch`